# Can you pass a parameter into a method to dynamicall call another method using python?

Tags: python, oop

I want to do something like this

```
def action(method_i_want_to_use):
  result = some_object.method_i_want_to_use() 
  return result
```

Is there a way to just pass in something as a parameter to dynamically decide what method will be called on an object?

Comment: Hi. In (http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions) you'll see that _parameters_ are the identifiers that are assigned to the objects passed as _arguments_. In other words , in ``def func(a,b=10):``, the names ``a`` and ``b`` are the parameters

Answer (score 4):

If `method_i_want_to_use` is a string you can do:

```
def action(method_i_want_to_use):
  result = getattr(some_object, method_i_want_to_use)()
  return result
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I like to do:

```
def action(method_i_want_to_use):
    if hasattr(some_object, method_i_want_to_use): # 2nd argument has to be a string
        f = getattr(some_object, method_i_want_to_use)
    else:
        #I'll leave this to you
        pass
    return f()
```

If you are trying to be dynamic, I think it's a good idea to check if the attribute exists as I've done above.

Comment: Just `return f()` - `getattr` takes care of binding to `some_object`.  Confirm: `fn = getattr("SDLKFJ","lower"); fn()` gives 'sdlkfj'. No need for `"SDLKFJ".fn()`.

Answer (score 0):

Because functions are objects in Python, you can pass the method and call it, like so:

```
class f:
    def __init__(self):
        self.quuz = 'quux'

    def foo(self):
        return self.quuz

    def bar(self, method=None):
        if (method):
            print(method())

a = f()
a.bar(a.foo)
```

But this requires passing the actual method in, rather than a string that contains the method name.

Comment: Simply use `method()` instead of `method.__call__()`

Comment: I thought there were some edge cases where method() wouldn't work, but I can't seem to find anything about it now, so well-taken.